# Are "phase-specific" masks ever used in the context of double exposure lithography? Can these sorts of things exist?

Tags: optics, visible-light, coherence

I was recently reading an 08' paper on [double exposure lithography](http://turroserver.chem.columbia.edu/PDF_db/publications_851_900/NJT869.pdf): and I was wondering if there existed *some* material that could be used to create a mask for e.g. a 193 nm light source that was *only opaque to light with a specific phase* $\theta$.

The idea, in the context of double exposure lithography, would be to overlay two masks, one opaque for light with some phase $\theta_a$ and another opaque for light with some phase $\theta_b$, where (in radians) 
$$\theta_a = \theta_b + \pi\cdot n$$ where $n$ is any non-zero integer value.  Thus, one could just phase-shift the source of coherent light used for lithography by $\pi$ radians to pattern with one mask and then the other.  This would save an alignment step for the substrate being patterned.

Is there any precedent for this sort of thing?  Or is this question nonsense?